# Manage multiple domains from one backend

Tags: customization, multisite, seo

I've want to organize all the content of multiple domains from one Wordpress back-end. Today I'd found the plug-in [MU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) from what I understand it redirects subdomains / folders to the domain with a 301.

Does this affect Google rankings? Can I edit all the content from one back-end? Some experiences or other suggestions to manage content from multiple domains from one back-end?

Also is there a limitation on how many domains can be in a network? Or do this completely depends on the server? What do I need if I would like to use around 20 domains? Many traffic, or big storage?

Comment: That plugin is now obsolete; all you need to do is set up mutisite and edit the URLs for the sites in your network.  The scaling question is dependent on the size/complexity/traffic, etc. of the network sites.  I'm going to guess that moving existing separate WP installs into a consolidated multisite is not going to be an easy task...

Comment: @CC is absolutely right. The plugin is obsolete for these past couple years. [Howto: Domain Mapping without a Plugin - Instructions](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/howto-domain-mapping-without-a-plugin-instructions).

Comment: Those instructions are good.  To take them to the next level you'd use Amazon Route 53 as the DNS; you can set up alias pointers to your root mutisite, never have to worry about a static IP address and also give your clients a "white label" set of DNS names so they never have to worry about screwing around with updating A or CNAME recs at their registrar.  It really is a slick solution.  I believe you can also do similar with CloudFlare.

Comment: @CC correct me if I'm wrong, but you say this plug-in is deprecated and Wordpress does support this out-of-the-box? 
Because when I'll add a new site in my network management I can only add subdomains. Where can I change the URL? I can't find anything about this, any good tutorials?

Comment: take a look at the link Max cited.

Comment: Oh sorry missed that one! Will look into it!